# Leaflet.markercluster issue with simple flat plane map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

## [Example here](http://codepen.io/jondlm/pen/dcuEx)

I am trying to add clustering to flat raster map of the US using leaflet. I've got most of the map working correctly and I can drop markers just fine. I am trying to add marker clusters like so:

```
var data = [
  [100,100],
  [100,110],
  [100,120]
];

var mapHeight = 500;
var mapWidth = 750;
var mapPadding = 100;
var imageUrl = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Blank_map_of_the_United_States.PNG';
var imageBounds = [[mapHeight, 0], [0, mapWidth]];

var map = L.map('leaflet-map', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 0,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple // Simple plane for easier X Y coordinate system
}).setView([mapHeight/2, mapWidth/2], 0); // center the map

// The bounds of the map including any specified padding
map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(
    [mapHeight + mapPadding, 0 - mapPadding],
    [0 - mapPadding, mapWidth + mapPadding]
));

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

data.forEach(function (i) {
  var m = new L.Marker(i);
  markers.addLayer(m); 
});

map.addLayer(markers); // This isn't working for some reason
```

I am not getting any javascript or css errors. Inspecting the DOM reveals that there are no cluster objects being created. I am working with *leaflet* 0.7.1 and *leaflet.markercluster* 0.2.

Could the problem have something to do with the `crs: L.CRS.Simple` projection I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using an out-of-date version of Leaflet MarkerCluster: use a new version and [it works perfectly](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jueyv).

Comment: Wow, thank you! I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. I thought I double checked my versions, but I guess I messed up!